# setting objects inside of objects that are dependant on eachother (Python)

Tags: python

I am attempting to insert enemies to my game, this one is called `punching_bag`, and I have made another object that is inside of `punching_bag` that is under the `DangerZone` class.

I want the `DangerZone` class to be next to the `punching_bag`. Hence the `punching_bag.x - 64`. But I am running into problems, because `punching_bag.x` doesn't exist yet I can not refer to it

`Enemy` Class

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, sprite, x, y, health, attack):
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.attack = attack
```

`DangerZone` Class

```
class DangerZone:
    def __init__(self, sprite, x, y, damage):
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.damage = damage
```

`punching_bag` Object

```
punch_bag = Enemy(sprite junk, 640, 0, 10,
              DangerZone(sprite junk, punch_bag.x - 64, punch_bag.y, 1)
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  You are attempting to reference an attribute of an object that doesn't yet exist. But when it does exist, you know its `x` attribute is going to have the value `640`, and `y` will have `0`, right?  So why not just do:

```
punch_bag = Enemy(sprite junk, 640, 0, 10,
              DangerZone(sprite junk, 640 - 64, 0, 1)
              )
```

You could wrap this in a factory function that took an `x` and `y` to be clearer what those values are and to make sure that the two uses of each provide the same value.  So maybe:

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, sprite, x, y, health, attack):
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.attack = attack

   @staticmethod 
   def create_with_danger_zone(sprite_junk, x, y, health, attack):
      return Enemy(sprite_junk, x, y, health,
                      DangerZone(sprite_junk, x - 64, y, 1))

punch_bag = Enemy.create_with_danger_zone(sprite_junk, 640, 0, 10)
```

Comment: For some reason this only works if I get rid of attack and just have the DangerZone
But then I can't refer to DangerZone. Am I doing something wrong or is somthing wrong with the function?